# How to change body of API POST request with script?

Tags: javascript, api, postman

I just started learning about API an hour ago and wanted input on a little POST I wrote. My understanding of how all of this works is very wrong. More than anything, I would like to know how to pass a variable from script to the API request.

The body:

```
{
   "bot_id" : "abc123",
   "text" : words
}
```

And the pre-request script in javascript:

```
var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

switch(num)
{
    case 1:
        words = "Hello world!";
        break;
    case 2:
        words = "Greetings Earthlings.";
        break;
    case 3:
        words = "Goodbye cruel world!";
        break;
}
```

This is the response I get when it fails (400 Bad Request):

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 400,
        "errors": [
            "Invalid bot_id"
        ]
    },
    "response": null
}
```

Comment: What's wrong about it? What questions do you have that tutorials haven't answered? What's the actual question here?

Comment: The purpose of this code is not clear... but it has nothing wrong.

Comment: what server side code are you using for your api?

Comment: The request succeeds when "text" : "hello" but fails when "text" : words. It seems the variable is not being read. The biggest question is, how do I pass a variable from script to request body? I haven't been able to find a tutorial that covers that.

Comment: The purpose is merely to post a phrase, designated by "text". I am not sure what the server-side code would be considered. This is the raw and the pre-request script, and I'm using Postman to POST to a URL.

Comment: How does it fail? We can't see your machine.

Comment: Give me a moment and I'll add it to the question. Thank you for the push in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

## The Response

The Response *`"errors": ["Invalid bot_id"]`* tells you that the `bot_id` (`abc123`) is wrong. May be there is some validation on the backend?

## How to Pass Values to the Request

Inside the pre-request script you have access to the `postman` object. This object has the methods `setGlobalVariable`, `getGlobalVariable`, `setEnvironmentVariable` and `getEnvironmentVariable`.

Now with this methods you can read/write variables. In your case you want to use  `postman.setGlobalVariable('words', words)`. Inside the body you can use the variables by using curly braces `{{variable}}`

### Code

#### Pre-Request Script

```
var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
var words = "";

switch(num) {
    case 1:
        words = "Hello world!";
        break;
    case 2:
        words = "Greetings Earthlings.";
        break;
    case 3:
        words = "Goodbye cruel world!";
        break;
}

postman.setGlobalVariable('words', words)
```

#### Body

```
{
    "bot_id" : "abc123",
    "text" : "{{words}}"
}
```

Comment: That's just it; the bot_id is only invalid when not "text" : "some hard coded value". I tried the code edits you made with the set variable and the curly braces. It got the same response as before.